# tensor flow conv3d works extremely slowly

Tags: tensorflow, 3d, neural-network, convolution

I'm building a 3D convolution NN which takes a tensor of shape (100,50,50,50,1). I'm using tf.conv3d and the filter size is (4,4,4). The codes worked when I only use one sample(1,50,50,50,1) instead of batch training. It took like forever for computing the conv3d with batch training. Anyone had any idea to solve this? thanks!

Comment: What do you mean forever? Does the program hang indefinitely? CNNs are slow especially if you're not using a modern GPU (even then complex networks can still be very slow). Difficult to say more unless you post an example of the issue you're having.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually not using GPU for now. Just CPU. I tested 2D convolution and it works great. So I assume it should also work for 3D. But as you said, maybe I'd better use GPU for 3D? The code works. The only issue is that it takes about 3 minutes to calculate just one epoch.

Comment: Yes that may help, but consider how many more calculations need to take place in `3D` vs. `2D` convolution. For example 2D:`4x4x50x50 = 40,000` multiplications for a single channel conv2d vs 3D:`4x4x4x50x50x50 = 8,000,000` for a single channel conv3d.

Comment: Yeah I have to use a 3D filter for my problem.. I have seen people saying that for tensorflow conv3d is not as optimized as conv2d. I'm currently using tf 1.1.0. Do you think that will be a problem?

Comment: Not sure about difference between TF versions, but as my previous comment indicates you should expect no better than a 200x slowdown due to the increased number of computations (assuming the 3rd dimension is the same as the original 2).